# Upgrading Remote Distributor in SQL Server Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, distributed-databases

I'm upgrading my remote distributor from 2005 to 2008r2, it is performing transactional replication only. this is a prerequisite to completing an upgrade of the Publisher to 2008r2.

Script replication environment.

STOP REPLICATION FROM PUBLICATIONS
Run commands to flush distribution database
Backup distribution DB
Remove SQL Server 2005
Install SQL Server 2008 R2
Service Pack SQL Server
Assign Permissions to Snapshot Directory
Check PAL permissions
Recreate replication Publications
Recreate replication agents
Recreate replication subscriptions

reapply indexes to the subscribers? (if a new snapshot is applied)
reapply maintenance jobs

if the snapshot directory remains the same with snapshots taken in 2005, will a new install of SQL 2008r2 use these snapshots or will it generate a new snapshot ?
 (not a massive issue at 3am, but just for my estimated timings)

Do I need to remove the distribution ServerName from sys.servers on the Publisher Server ? is anything left in the system tables that I should clear out manually ?

I wanted to change the security to be windows based security as its currently running under 'sa' login. (obviously not good). But have had issues getting this to function after changing the initial config, so thought it might be useful to do it at initial reinstall and switch to 'sa' if unsuccessful.

Thanks